# Speed up numpy indexing resulting from unravel_index?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some code that uses the result of an unravel_index command to access elements of some matrices.  I did some line-profiling and just accessing these elements and storing them in new arrays is taking somewhere around 25-30% of my run time.  Is there a way to speed up this indexing at all?

Comment: Show some code for context, 25-30% with respect to unknown code gives us no idea if it is slow or fast.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  The code that uses the indexing would be hard to post in isolation, since it also calls lots of other functions.  Does it help at all to know that the rest of the function involves things like np.dot and other matrix-vector operations (like A*B, A**2, etc)?

Comment: There have been other SO questions about speeding up calculations like `C[i,j,...] = np.dot(A[i,j,..], B[i,j,...]' for all `i,j`.  `np.einsum` can be a powerful alternative to `np.dot` in these cases.

Comment: One basic step is to minimize the number of times (per loop) that you do the indexing.  `x=A[i,j...]; np.dot(x,...) * x**2` etc.

Comment: It might help if you specify (roughly) the dimensions and shapes of the arrays.  Which are you iterating on, and which go into vector operations?  Also are you doing basic indexing or advanced?  Advanced is much slower.

Comment: The shape is a 3 x N x 4 matrix, where N could vary anywhere from a few hundred to tens of thousands.  I'm only iterating on the outermost (4) index.  I believe it would be considered advanced indexing.

Comment: With `numpy` the 1st dimension is considered 'outermost', what we usually call 'rows'.  You might experiment with rotating axes so you are iterating over rows of a (4,3,N) array.  But 4 loops with N or 3N vectorized arrays sounds pretty good to me.